# Error with specific name using rest client builder in grails 2.3.4

Tags: json, rest, grails, groovy, dspace

I'm using rest-client-builder:1.0.3 grails plugin to communicate with the REST API DSpace. 
This works well:

```
def resp = rest.post("http://10.42.0.239:8080/rest/login"){
        contentType "application/json"
        json{
            email = "myemail@mail"
            password = "root"
        }
    }
```

but I need to send a parameter with a minus sign in this way:

```
def status = rest.get("http://10.42.0.239:8080/rest/status"){
            contentType "application/json"
            json{
                rest-dspace-token = "4506b187-bda8-4db7-801d-635f277d5316"
            }
        }
```

Minus signs in rest-dspace-token give the next error:

```
((rest - dspace) - token) is a binary expression, but it should be a variable expression at line
```

How can i solve this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The problem is not with the data, it is with the header.
In version 2.1.1 of rest-client-builder the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Just quote it as a property of delegate:

```
        json{
            delegate.'rest-dspace-token' = "4506b187-bda8-4db7-801d-635f277d5316"
        }
```